# How to split the drop down menus WordPress walker on columns?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How to split the drop down menus WordPress walker on columns?
How to split the drop-down menus into columns using WP-Bootstrap-Navwalker? as here:[dropdown-menu with 3 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyzi1.png)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Navigation-->
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="mainNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills ">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="page/company.html">page1</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="servicesjs">Page2</a>
        <div class="container-fluid dropdown-menu submenu1 multi-column columns-3 ">
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4><a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/repairs.html">Header Link</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/repairs_hydrocylindrs.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/hydromotors.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/piston-pumps.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/hydraulic-distributor.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/hydro_rotators.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/dosing_pumps.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/hydraulic-molot.html">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4><a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/diagnostics.html">Header2 Link</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/diagnostics2.html"> Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/test_stend.html"> Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4><a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/diagnostics.html">Header Link</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/stend.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/pneumatic.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/turning_works.html">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="stockjs">Page3</a>
        <div class="container-fluid dropdown-menu submenu2 multi-column columns-3 ">
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4><a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/sale.html"> Header Link</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/stocks_trumpets.html"> Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/rod.html"> Link</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4> <a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/sale.html">Header Link</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/making_cylinders.html"> Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/rvd.html">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4> <a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/sale.html">Header Link</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/new_hydro.html">Header Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="page/contact.html">Page4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- End navigation-->
```

```html
<!-- Navigation WordPress-->
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'depth'    => 2, // 1 = with dropdowns, 0 = no dropdowns.
 'container'   => 'div',
 'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
 'container_id'  => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
 'menu_class'  => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
    'fallback_cb'  => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'   => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
) );
?>

</nav>
<!-- Navigation-->
```

Standard menu WP-Bootstrap-Nav Walker.
How to split the drop-down menus into columns using WP-Bootstrap-Navwalker?
I would like to see the options without using different plug-ins for WP

Answer (score 2):

Navwalker dropdown can be split into a specified number of columns using CSS column-count.

Example (target the ul list):

```
.elementy-ul {
-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 100px;
width: 100%;
```

}

Helpful? Read more on [CSS column count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)